# Сортировка точек на плоскости по/против часовой стрелки

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, вычислительная-геометрия

Есть набор точек типа `std::pair<int, int>`, представляющих собой вершины некоторого многоульника (вообще говоря, невыпуклого). Дана некоторая вершина из набора. Необходимо отсортировать набор так, чтобы он начинался с этой стартовой вершины и далее шёл по/против часовой стрелки.

Comment: Функцию пробегающую по координатам можно сделать. Проверять следующую вершину  (против часовой) по какому либо правилу
например если есть вершина у которой x меньше и y меньше, то она следующая, если такой нет, то искать вершину с x меньше и y равным, потом с x меньшим и y большим... и т.д

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложил было такой вариант... Берем такую функцию - [`atan2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2), она вроде как аккуратно углы рассчитывает. Сортируем по углу. Начиная с нужной нам вершины идем до конца массива, потом добираем оставшиеся точки в том же направлении по массиву, но с другого конца.

Но в общем случае это не годится. Вопрос - относительно чего считать углы, относительно какой точки? Если она задана и находится внутри многоугольника - то описанный вариант годится.

Но если ее нет - задача вообще оказывается неоднозначна. Лень рисовать, представьте себе 5 точек - 4 в вершинах квадрата, по часовой - 1,2,3,4. и 0 - в его центре.

01234 - искомый вариант, если за центр взять, например, половину высоты от 0 на сторону 23. Но точно так же годится 02341 - только точка на высоте от 0 на сторону 34...

Если все равно, какое решение принять - то как вариант, построить [выпуклую оболочку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%93%D1%80%D1%8D%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0), потом выбрать одну из точек - например, нижнюю, а уж потом все остальные отсортировать и построить эдакую "звездочку" :)